# How to find the text of anonymous jtextfield

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

So i am making a shop system with a gui. I have a menu item that when i press it opens another jframe to input the number of each item sold in a jtextfield, like this:

```java
JPanel salesPanel = new JPanel();
setSize(new Dimension(520,270));
setResizable(false);
setLocation(200,200);
        
title = new JLabel("<html><u><b>Fill in the number of products sold.</b></u></html>");
        
salesPanel.setSize(new Dimension(230,30*sw.getProductList().size()));
salesPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(sw.getProductList().size()+1,3));
...
sw.getProductList().forEach(n ->{
    salesPanel.add(new JLabel(Integer.toString(n.getProductID())+":"));
    salesPanel.add(new JLabel(Integer.toString(n.getQuantity())));
    salesPanel.add(new JLabel(n.getName()));
    salesPanel.add(new JTextField());
});
```

This is how it looks.

[image: this is how it looks]

Note that `sw` is the object of the main class which has an `ArrayList` of the type product which contains the information of each product.

Is there any way that I can text from these `JTextField`s ? And if not what is another way that I can do this.

EDIT:
in the main ShopWindow class, I have an ArrayList

```
private ArrayList<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

class product:

```
public class Product {
    private int productID;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;
    private boolean isPerishable;
    private double totalProdValue;
    ...getters and setters for each field
```

Comment: Why not simply create a class with proper fields and getters, including JTextField field and a getter to get its text? You seem to be over-complicating things unnecessarily. Also, the child window should be a JDialog, not a JFrame, modal dialog if need be...

Comment: Alright i changed it to a jdialog but whats the difference?
Also, i can just make a class that contains a jtextfield and add it to the panel?, how will i identify them when getting the text? sorry this is my first big java swing program.

Comment: What do you want to do with the text from each `JTextField`? Do you want to verify that a valid value was entered? Do you need it when the _Update Inventory_ button is pressed?

Comment: yep both, i was planning to check if it was valid and then reduce the quantity of the product and re calculate the totals once the Update Inventory button is pressed.

Comment: @Quantum3 why JDialog? Becuase it is an industry best practice to use that class for internal windows. Also, as Hovercraft Full of Eels suggested, don't use anonymous components if you intend to reference them later on. This complicates things unnecessarily.

Comment: @Quantum3 for text fields, you may want to implement add document listeners to validate the inputs as they are typed (i.e. not allow non-numeric characters). Then, an action listener for the "update inventory" to do the rest. To make your action simple, you may want to have each row to be in it's own JPanel with a method that reads the value of the JTextField and sets the value of the JLabel. You should make this method public so that the action listener can invoke it for each row JPanel. Let me know if you need me to mock this.

Comment: @hfontanez it would be really appreciated if you mock it :) thanks for this.

Comment: I suggest adding an [input verifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) to each `JTextField`. Regarding reducing the quantity and re-calculating the totals, I can't help you based on the code you posted in your question. I may be able to post a relevant answer if you [edit] your question and post a [mcve].

Comment: @Abra i think im fine with reducing the quantity and calculating the totals, but in my mind i was thinking that when i click the update inventory butten i loop through the jtextfields and getting the text then editing the arraylist in another class. However i coded myself into a  corner here ...

Comment: An input verifier can also be used to reduce the quantity and calculate totals. No need to loop through the `JTextField`s when clicking the _Update Inventory_ button. That's why I asked for a [mcve]. Like you wrote in your last comment, you have _coded myself into a corner_

Comment: @Abra i tried to edit the question by giving you information. but basically there is a menu where i can add products, display a table of products and remove a product. When i add a product a child window is opened and the same with the remove product. Displaying displays the table of products to the main window... i hope this helps. 
Also with the input verifiers, do i add them to the anonymous jtextfields or what?

Comment: 1) **Don't use text fields for numbers!** Instead declare `SpinnerNumberModel` instances as attributes of the class (possibly as an array or in an array list) and display those number models in spinners (a `JSpinner`). This makes it easy for the user, and easy for the code in that there is no 'number validation' to be done. When finding the number, simply call `numberModel.getNumber().getInteger()`. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Start with just 2 items. If you can solve it for 2, the rest should be simple.

Comment: 3) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) (And just in case..) 4) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: @AndrewThompson the number spinner thing worked! Thank you very much, however is there a way to set the default value of the spinners to null as i would like the user to type in a simple number. As it is, if you type in 2 in a spinner it becomes 20, since there is 0 already there. Nevertheless this worked and i will use it anyway.

Comment: *"is there a way to set the default value of the spinners to null"* Sorry, not that I know of. One strategy might be to set it to a number that does not make any sense, like -1. But I think that would be confusing for many users. Note that the user can also use the up/down arrows (on the keyboard) to adjust a spinner. That's the method I usually use.

Comment: Yep, i just found out that you can use the arrows ill make sure to point that out to the user. Thanks a lot!

Comment: *"Yep, i just found out .."* Tip: Add @Abra (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. I'm closing this tab in my browser now, so if you want my further attention, be sure to tag me.

Comment: @Quantum3 did my example help you?

Comment: Yes @hfontanez, I used this and learnt a lot from this thread, thank you

Comment: @Quantum3 then, if the answer satisfied your question, I would appreciate you upvote and mark my answer as the solution.

Comment: @hfontanez i have less than 15 reputation can't upvote sorry ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a mock solution (only meant to show how to update qty label and clear fields using action listeners)

```
public class MockFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel framePanel = new JPanel();
        ProductPanel bananaPanel = new ProductPanel("268", "25", "Bananas");
        ProductPanel sugarPanel = new ProductPanel("321", "200", "Sugar");
        
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton update = new JButton("Update");
        JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        
        buttonPanel.setSize(400, 30);
        update.setSize(50, 20);
        cancel.setSize(50, 20);
        buttonPanel.add(update);
        buttonPanel.add(cancel);
        
        update.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                bananaPanel.setNewQty();
                sugarPanel.setNewQty();
            }
        });

        cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                bananaPanel.clearField();
                sugarPanel.clearField();
            }
        });
        
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        framePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(framePanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        framePanel.add(bananaPanel);
        framePanel.add(sugarPanel);
        framePanel.add(buttonPanel);
        frame.add(framePanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private static class ProductPanel extends JPanel {
        private JLabel productId = new JLabel();
        private JLabel qty = new JLabel();
        private JLabel name = new JLabel();
        private JTextField field = new JTextField();
        
        public ProductPanel(String id, String amount, String itemName) {
            this.setSize(400, 30);
            this.field.setSize(100, 20);
            this.field.setColumns(5);
            
            productId.setText(id);
            qty.setText(amount);
            name.setText(itemName);
            
            this.add(productId);
            this.add(qty);
            this.add(name);
            this.add(field);
        }

        public void clearField() {
            field.setText("");
        }
        
        public void setNewQty() {
            String newQty = field.getText();
            if (newQty != null && !newQty.isBlank()) {
                qty.setText(newQty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main points of this mocked solution:

1. Use a `JPanel` to encapsulate a product line item. This will make it easier if you need to remove and/or add product rows.
2. The product panel contains a method to update qty or clear the fields that will be invokable by the frame buttons (depending on which is clicked).
3. Simplicity of design - Creating a generic panel for the product eliminate repetitive code.

Obviously, you would have to modify this so that you use the proper layout manager or use absolute positioning to properly aligned components to your liking. Also, you would need to create a Panel for the table header and add the remaining of your products.  Also, you may want to break this into public classes and even maybe create a separate class for your frame.

The action listeners could also have a "for-each" loop to update each `ProductPanel` instead of hard coding each panel individually. That should look something like this:

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JPanel panel = (JPanel)((JButton) e.getSource()).getParent().getParent();
            Component[] components = panel.getComponents();
            for (Component c : components) {
                if (c instanceof ProductPanel) {
                    ((ProductPanel)c).setNewQty();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Obviously, your solution will depend on how you decide to encapsulate your components in containers. For this mock, the product panels are inside the frame panel which contains the panels where the buttons were placed. Therefore, I need to get the "grandparent" container for the update and cancel buttons to take advantage of calling the appropriate methods to update and clear in a more dynamic way.

Lastly, you may want to do something more elegant for creating your product panels. For example, you may want to add some factory method to create your product panel instead of having hard-coded product panels like my mock solution. Anyway, I think I demonstrated the solution you were looking for.

**UPDATE**: If you don't follow Andrew Thompson's recommendation of not using text fields for numeric values, the panel's `getNewQty` method would need to validate the text obtained to make sure it contains a valid numeric value (which was his point). I would **STRONGLY** recommend you follow his advice.

Comment: You should also follow the recommendation made by Andrew Thompson, and not used `JTextField` for numeric fields.